# Bash: Comparing Strings

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, curl

I am trying to write a script to test whether a website is available. I have got the `curl` trick from http://droptips.com/quick-command-to-check-the-status-of-a-url-linux-bsd-os-x an it returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` if it’s OK.

I now want to put that into an `if … else` block, and this is where it’s falling apart. When I try the following in Bash (no script yet):

```
test=`curl -Is https://internotes.net | head -n 1`; \
echo "$test"; \
echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"; \
if [ "$test" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; \
then \
    echo 'Good'; \
else \
    echo 'Bad'; \
fi
```

It always returns something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Bad
```

The two strings look the same, but the comparison appears to fail.

What is the correct way to test this?

Comment: Why are you using `; \` at the end of lines? They essentially cancel each other out -- the semicolon acts as a command separator, and the backslash prevents the newline prevents the newline from acting as a command separator. Just remove both, and let the newline have its normal function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It differs, because `$test` contains a CR (ASCII 13) at end of line. Change the first line to:

```
test=` curl -Is https://internotes.net | head -n 1 | tr -d '\r' `
```

Comment: Using either backticks or the `$()` syntax, I’m still getting the second result (`Bad`).

Comment: @Giles Quenot: Wrong place for the critics. This is only a minimal edit of the original source. So comment the original post.

Comment: @Manngo: Here, the result is `good` after suggested change.

Comment: @Wiimm You’re right. I must have mis-typed it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No need 2 pipes here. Answered a solution with just a `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

httpcode=$(curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null 'https://stackoverflow.com')

if ((httpcode >= 200 && httpcode < 400)); then
    [...]
```

If you insist to use your comparison of string, use:

```
$ output="$(curl -Is https://internotes.net | head -n 1)"
$ echo "$output" | od -c
0000000   H   T   T   P   /   1   .   1       2   0   0       O   K  \r
0000020  \n
0000021
$ if [ "$output" = $'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r' ]; then echo ok; else echo NOTOK; fi
ok
$ if [[ $output == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"* ]]; then echo ok; else echo NOTOK; fi
ok
```

Note that you have `\r\n`, you can just ignore the right of the string with

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"*
```

with the `[[  ]]` form. Note the usefulness here :)

But in a more general case, if you need to compare strings in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), the recommended way is:

```
if [[ string == another ]]
```

or using regex:

```
if [[ string =~ regex ]]
```

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.

---

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

The backquote

```
`
```

is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082